# Cordova 9 is not adding service tag into AndroidManifest.xml from my custom plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a custom Cordova plugin developed for Android. This was working fine with Cordova 7.1. Recently I updated my Cordova version to Cordova 9. Now  section is not added in AndroidManifest.xml

plugin.xml

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
 <service
 ...
 </service>
</config-file>
```

I suppose to see the below tag in AndroidManifest.xml. However, it is missing after Cordova 9 update.

```
<service android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">
...
</service>
```

Tried removing platform and plug-in manually and added help. Still issue persist.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and it tooks me ages to figure it out:

Change `parent="/manifest/application"` to `parent="application"` and it should work.